# Dependent Dropdown issues in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-fields

I am using two select boxes in my form: one for country and one for state. I want the states box to be displayed based on the selection of the country box.

I also have two database tables: countries and states.  The  country's table structure is { Country Code and Country Name } and the states table structure is { Country Code and State Name }.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: follow instructions on this post : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10112/dynamic-select-list-in-the-form-dependent-dropdown

hope it helps

PR

Comment: Yeah i followed it but I am not able to get the desired results.. Please help..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module.

[Demos and showcase](http://wimleers.com/demo/hierarchical-select)